# JavaScript Challenge--Rails Button Iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

On my `welcome#index` page, there's a button to write a new `Comment` for an `Article`, remotely (or should I say asynchronously), using AJAX.

It works perfectly except that when an article is iterated, using rails, the browser treats the JS button as the same button throughout all iterated elements (articles).

My guess is that JS iteration is required.

How does one solve this?

`# welcome/index.html.haml`

```
- @articles.each do |article|
        = link_to "Comment", new_article_comment_path(article), class: "write-button", remote: true
        = link_to "Close", root_path, class: "close-button", remote: true
        = link_to "Commented", root_path, class: "written-button", remote: true
        #comment-form{ :style => "display:none;" }
```

`#comments/new.js.erb`

```
$( '#comment-form' ).html('<%= j render ("form") %>');
$( '#comment-form' ).slideDown( "slow ");
$( '.write-button' ).hide();
$( '.close-button' ).show();
```

`#comments/create.js.erb`

```
$( '#comment-form' ).slideUp(350);
$( '.close-button' ).hide();
$( '.written-button' ).show();
```

`#welcome.js`

```
//slide up and return
$( '.close-button' ).hide();
$( '.close-button' ).on('click', function() {
    $( '#comment-form' ).slideUp(350);
    $( '.close-button' ).hide();
    $( '.write-button' ).show();
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by *the browser treats the JS button as the same button throughout all iterated elements (articles).*?

Comment: For example, the AJAX works perfectly for the *first* article iterated but then when a user clicks the write-a-comment button for the second article iterated, it would treat the second JS button the same as the first and open the form in the *first* article.

Comment: Can you post an image of that on what is happening currently? or a fiddle?

Comment: Ok. I got it. Writing an answer :)

Comment: Great! Much appreciated....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you need to provide an `id` for the `comment-form` div which equals to the `article.id`, so that the `form` shows up for that respected `article`.

```
%div{:id => "comment-form-#{article.id}", :style => "display:none;"}
```

And change the `comments/new.js.erb` to below

```
#comments/new.js.erb

$( "#comment-form-<%= params[:article_id] %>").html('<%= j render ("form") %>');
$( "#comment-form-<%= params[:article_id] %>" ).slideDown( "slow ");
$( '.write-button' ).hide();
$( '.close-button' ).show();
```

Comment: Works for the form! How do I take care of the buttons as well?